# Removing joints with Farseer

Tags: unity-game-engine, box2d, farseer

I'm using [Farseer](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/) in Unity and I'm having difficulty figuring out how to remove joints using script. I want to remove all the joints in my scene. I've been trying to use things like: world.JointList and world.RemoveJoint but since in Unity the joints are components (ie FSPulleyJointComponent) I don't understand how to access the joint itself.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad... world.JointList and world.RemoveJoint both work fine. I wasn't getting the world properly.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used `Farseer`, but if joints are implemented as `Components` than they can be removed using [Object.Destroy](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html).

If `Destroy` is used on a `Component`'s reference, then it will be removed from the `GameObject` it's attached to.